# How does 'compass watch' work/how is it used with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, compass-sass

I have done `compass create .` and `compass init rails` whilst in my project directory. A few questions:

- I have placed my `.sass` files in `public/stylesheets`. Is this the right place to put them?
- When I run `compass watch`, it does not automatically compile these `.sass` files. I have to manually specify the files: `compass watch public/stylesheets/myfile.sass` etc. How do I get this working automatically?
- The files `ie.css`, `print.css` and `screen.css` have been placed in `stylesheets/compiled`. How do I remove these without them reappeareing after compilation?
- My own compiled `.sass` files are compiled to `compiled/ts`. Why are they in `ts` and not in `compiled`?

Many thanks in advance

---

**Edit:** Worked it out:

- No, put them in `app/stylesheets/`
- Works if you follow above
- Remove them from `app/stylesheets/`
- Do first answer and they will be put in `compiled/`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compass uses a configuration file located in "config/compass.rb"  which tells it where the important directories are.  I think it knows to look in config/compass.rb because it searches a list of predefined directories for a compass.rb config file

Heres the config file I use for my Rails 3 projects

```
# This configuration file works with both the Compass command line tool and within Rails.
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
project_type = :rails
project_path = Compass::AppIntegration::Rails.root
# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "public/stylesheets"
sass_dir = "app/stylesheets"
images_dir = "public/images"
environment = Compass::AppIntegration::Rails.env
# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true
preferred_syntax = :sass
```

I generate this file by running the following command from the Rails root:

```
compass init rails --css-dir=public/stylesheets --sass-dir=app/stylesheets --images-dir=public/images -x sass --using blueprint/basic
```

This is the only command that I use to run compass, and I run it when generating my project through a rails template  https://github.com/sid137/rails-templates/blob/master/rails3.rb .  I constructed this command by reading through the compass help, and looking online, as I wanted to customize all of my compass setup.   Now, I can immediately begin my projects with

```
compass watch .
```

or

```
compass compile .
```

Comment: What do you mean by `# Require any additional compass plugins here.`, I'm trying to get compass to work with zurb-foundation, so should I write `require 'zurb-foundation` here or something like that? Thanks.

Comment: Hey, i don't remember exactly what I meant by that (haven't used compass since then)  but was probably referring to things such as here: http://compass-style.org/frameworks/    The this plugin, for example, the installation is just as you have described:  https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass-colors

Comment: Thanks, I got my answer! To those interested: putting the require for the particular plugin you want to install inside of the file "config/compass.config" or simply "config.rb" at the root of the project (two special places that are searched by default by the compass binary for config settings) will make it available through command line. In my example, when putting `require 'zurb-foundation'` I will be able to use `compass install foundation` from the command line.