# compass-960-plugin does not install properly

Tags: rubygems, sass, compass-sass, 960.gs

I'm trying to utilize compass/sass/960 grid system.  However, it doesn't seem like compass-960-plugin is installing properly.

The error message I am receiving:

$ compass watch
LoadError on line 105 of /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/compass/configuration/data.rb: no such file to load -- ninesixty
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace

And here's the trace:

$ compass watch --trace
LoadError on line 105 of /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/compass/configuration/data.rb: no such file to load -- ninesixty
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/compass/configuration/data.rb:105:in `require'
  /var/www/wgu/config.rb:1:in`parse_string'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:40:in `parse_string'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:35:in`_parse'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:34:in `open'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:34:in`_parse'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:13:in `new_from_file'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:39:in`configuration_for'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:83:in `add_project_configuration'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/compass/commands/project_base.rb:31:in`add_project_configuration'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/compass/commands/project_base.rb:25:in `configure!'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/compass/commands/project_base.rb:15:in`initialize'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/compass/commands/update_project.rb:26:in `initialize'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:38:in`new'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:38:in `perform!'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in`run!'
  /usr/bin/compass:26

$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]

$ gem -v
1.3.7

$ compass version
Compass 0.10.6
Copyright (c) 2008-2009 Chris Eppstein
Released under the MIT License.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you installed compass / plugins as sudo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it had something to do with the version of Ubuntu server I had installed. I couldn't seem to install all these tools properly on that version. So, ultimately, I installed the latest version of Ubuntu server and was able to install all these tools properly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I've been having some trouble with this as well. Currently I have to add "-r ninesixty" to force compass to load the plugin every time I want to run a command. (It doesn't seem to be respecting the require statement in compass.rb) Give it a try with that flag and see if it helps:

```
compass watch -r ninesixty
```

**EDIT:**
Duh! Mere seconds later on the sidebar of this question I find: [How does 'compass watch' work/how is it used with rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486879/how-does-compass-watch-work-how-is-it-used-with-rails)

The compass.rb file goes in your config/ 
Make sure it includes

```
require 'ninesixty'
```

and compass should go happily about it's day.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it had something to do with the version of Ubuntu server I had installed.  I couldn't seem to install all these tools properly on that version.  So, ultimately, I installed the latest version of Ubuntu server and was able to install all these tools properly.  Thanks for the help!